# Maven project not built pom.xml error

Tags: maven, build, dependencies

I deleted a dependency in pom.xml but still get this error: **dependency = [com.viewpagerindicator: library: apklib: 2.3.1: compile] not found in workspace.**
I looked in the build path and there is no dependence apklib there.
 What should I do to get rid of this error?
Thanks !

Comment: Have you performed `mvn clean`?

Comment: try mvn dependency:tree to find out where it comes from - it might be a transitive dependency

Comment: Presumably this is an IDE error? What IDE? Have you refreshed your workspace? Are you using in-built Maven support in your IDE?

Comment: If you use Eclipse, try right click project, choose Maven -> Update Project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I performed mvn clean and its build now ! Thanks For help !